# Find the sum of the first ten terms

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation, contest-math

How do I find the sum below?

$$\sum_{i=1}^{10}\frac{2i+1}{i^2(i+1)^2}$$

I think there should be a simpler way instead of just adding the ten terms up using brute force, since it's impossible to do that in less than 10 minutes in a contest, because the terms starting on the 4th one is ugly, and even uglier to get the common denominator.

Can someone give me some idea for this?

Comment: Just notice that you have $(i+1)^2-i^2$ there.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Note that
$$
\frac{2i+1}{i^{2} (i+1)^{2}}
=
\frac{1}{i^{2}} - \frac{1}{(i+1)^{2}}.
$$

See under [telescoping series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series).